# Kube Cluster under high load has time out errors when connecting to an external service

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have two azure kube clusters, each is connecting to ms dynamics. And under high load (hundreds of calls/min), the connection starts throwing timed out errors ("`org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException`").   About 10% of the time.

AND, this error seems to be coming from specific nodes.  So if there are 20 pods spread across 8 nodes, only the pods that are on say 4 of the nodes will experience the error.  The other pod/nodes are handling just as many calls, but no errors.

This is over many days too. So the same pod/nodes have had the error over the course of 10 day.

Has anyone experienced this?
How can I trouble shoot this?

NOTE: These are not 429 connection refused errors.

Comment: Can you share logs from affected nodes & pods?

Comment: What is your disk size? You may be getting throttled. Check network and IO stats.